# How to use custom CSS to change the distance between the header and top of the page/where the page starts?

Tags: html, css, squarespace

How can I use custom CSS on the site www.izzofit.com to change the distance/padding between the start of the header/nav and the top of the page, as well as the bottom, and between the header and where the page starts?

Also, if I could change the padding between where the text/gallery starts on the page and the beginning of the page too, that'd be great.

```
#container-content {
    padding: 0px 20px 75px
}
```

and

```
#navigator header#topBar ul#nav {
    padding: 20px 0 0px 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 25px;
}
```

Thanks,

Jared

Comment: Rather then give us a sight reference can you give us example code.

Comment: I'll try to help you, but you really need to add the code to your question. Otherwise, this question will be useless as a reference to future visitors, and will probably be closed.

Comment: Consider familiarizing yourself with question-asking best practices. See [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I used Squarespace to create this website, and once I figure out which part of the code does what the question is asking I can definitely put the code in. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find `#nav` in your CSS

Currently it contains a `padding-top` of 35px.

Adjust this rule:

```
#nav { padding: 35px 0 25px 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wherever your padding is set, set it or what you want
For example:
Padding-top :0;
If you have not declared padding set it to 0.
You can do this for each side depending how much you want.